# Stuck on Path of Go Bridge Keeper Chapter IV

Tags: the-path-of-go

[This poster was stuck in the same place](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/633978/stuck-on-the-path-of-go).

[image: Image taken from that post]

This is the board image made by the other posters.  The game/puzzle begins without the numbered stones.

I've tried many many games and with the Komi of 6.5 (iirc) the best I can do is to lose by 0.5.

All attempts start at B5.

Then one path is to make a bamboo with B3, B4.

The other path I've tried is J6, D2, H3 and eventually take H5.

Depending on which random choices the AI makes, I can get at best 0.5.  And it seems to know way ahead what it's OK abandoning because it knows it will win.  So if I attack one area it just makes one move somewhere else to balance it out.

Is there a concept that I'm still missing that would allow me to "win handily" as the other forum posters suggest?  And are they also accounting for the Komi when they say that (your guess)?

Thanks!

Comment: In this particular case, I believe you will get better answers where the Go experts are and not where the video game experts are.

Comment: I fixed the tag on this game, which I think is what led to the confusion. Given that this is indeed about a puzzle in a video game, it is on topic.

Comment: Related meta: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/does-this-site-support-the-computerized-versions-of-board-games

Comment: This should be migrated to [boardgames.SE](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - As per the linked meta, this question is on-topic here, as it pertains to a specific puzzle within a video game version of Go.

Comment: @JasonBerkan Alright, let me rephrase:  This question would be better off on boardgames.SE, where there are a few Go experts.  I'll take a look at this puzzle when I get a chance tonight, but given my high kyu I doubt I'll be able to help.

Comment: I would be OK if this were migrated to boardgames.se - but I hate when questions are pushed out of an se site as off topic but it is pretty close and there are no better se candidate sites at the time of asking.  Although this question might also pertain to the AI-programming as well (though in this case the puzzle is probably well researched and not impacted by AI particulars)

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the Knights Move at B5 that finally helped me beat the bridge builder. Idk if you'll get this now beings that this is quite an old post but I thought I'd try to help.i hope this does help you out! I took a pic of my victory as well if you'd like it.